# Get request showing sending request forever in postman and in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to Build an API With Node.js, Express, & MongoDB. Everything seem to work so far.

I have connected mongodb to nodejs and try to fetch data using get request and request sends forever.

I tried get request in both chrome and postman, both are loading for a long time.

I am not sure if I have missed something out or if I am using incorrect syntax?

See my code below..

app.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cart'

mongoose.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true})

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
const con = mongoose.connection

con.on('open', function(){
    console.log("database connected..")
})

const cartRouter = require('./router/cart')
app.use('/cart',cartRouter)

app.listen(3030,() =>{
    console.log("listening...")
})
```

.....
cart.js
.....

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Cart = require('../router/cart')


router.get('/',async (req,res) =>{
    try{

        const carts = await Cart.find()
        res.send(carts)

    }catch(err){
        console,log(err)
    }    
})

module.exports = router
```

cart.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const cartschema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name : {
        type : String
    },
    price : {
        type : Number
    },
    qty : {
        type : Number
    }

})

const cart = mongoose.model("cart",cartschema)

module.exports = cart
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? also call the express.json function like this: app.use(express.json())

Comment: No I am not getting any errors..In console after displaying database connected nothing is coming.In get req it is sending req forever

Answer (score 0):

`use()` function is used to mount the specified middleware function(s) at the path which is being specified because of the wrong implementation your app is unable to proceed further. said soo you need to update
`app.use(express.json)` to  `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: I tried that and edited the question..still the issue persists

Comment: `const Cart = require('../router/cart')` is that reference correct? if yes then that can be a reason. because you are referring to the same router. @jayasree

Comment: but ideally, this should show an error ie: `TypeError: Cart.find is not a function` when you try to make a request.